Как сохранить и отобразить задачи пользователей в календаре после авторизации на JavaScript?
Делаю сайт список дел где есть архив, календарь.
Столкнулся с тем то что не могу сделать чтобы при авторизации на сайт сохранялись задачи этого пользователя в календаре, я так понимаю что я должен обращаться в localStorage и забирать от туда ключ, но для меня это очень сложно написать поэтому прошу помощи.
Код:
server.js
const registrationForm = document.getElementById('registration-form');
const loginForm = document.getElementById('login-form');

registrationForm.addEventListener('submit' , function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Получаем значения из формы
    const username = registrationForm.elements.username.value;
    const password = registrationForm.elements.password.value;

    // Сохраняем данные в localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('username', username);
    localStorage.setItem('password', password);

    // Оповещаем пользователя об успешной регистрации 
    alert('Вы успешно зарегистрировались!');
});

loginForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

        // Получаем значения из формы
        const username = loginForm.elements.username.value;
        const password = loginForm.elements.password.value;
    
        // Получаем сохраненые данные из localStorage
        const savedUsername = localStorage.getItem('username');
        const savedPassword = localStorage.getItem('password');

        //Проверяем, что введенные данные совподают с сохраненными
        if(username === savedUsername && password === savedPassword) {
            // Пользователь успешно авторизован
            alert('Вы успешно вошли!');
            // Получаем текст задачи
            const taskText = prompt('Введите текст задачи:');
            // Создаем ключ для хранения задачи в localStorage
            const taskKey = username + '_' + Date.now();
            // Сохраняем текст задачи в localStorage
            localStorage.setItem(taskKey, taskText);
        } else {
            //Ошибка авторизации 
            alert('Ошибка авторизации. Проверьте правильность введенных данных.');
        }
});

calendar.js
// Получаем элементы со страницы
const calendarDateInput = document.getElementById('calendarDate');
const taskListOnDate = document.getElementById('taskListOnDate');
const now = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0]; 
// Устанавливаем текущую дату в поле ввода календаря
calendarDateInput.value = now;
// Фиксируем текущую дату
const fixedDate = now;
// Функция для отображения задач для определенной даты и пользователя
function displayTasksForDate(date, username) {
    // Очищаем список задач на выбранную дату
    taskListOnDate.innerHTML = "";
    const currentTime = new Date();
// Перебираем все элементы в localStorage
    for (let key in localStorage) {
            // Пропускаем ключ 'archivedTasks'
        if (key === 'archivedTasks') continue;
            // Проверяем, что ключ начинается с имени пользователя
        if (key.startsWith(username + '_')) {
            const taskData = localStorage.getItem(key);
            
            
            if (taskData) {
                const taskParts = taskData.split(",");
            if (taskParts.length === 2) {
                const savedTaskText = taskParts[0];
                const savedTaskTime = new Date(taskParts[1]);
                // Проверяем совпадение даты задачи с выбранной датой
                if (savedTaskTime.toISOString().split("T")[0] === date) {
                    const taskItem = document.createElement('li');
                    taskItem.setAttribute('data-taskKey', key);
                    // Рассчитываем разницу времени между текущим временем и временем задачи
                    const difference = savedTaskTime - currentTime;
                    const daysleft = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                    const hoursLeft = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                    const minutesleft = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                     // Заполняем элемент списка информацией о задаче и таймером
                    taskItem.innerHTML = `
                        <span>${savedTaskText}</span>
                        <span id="timer" class="obschiyspan">${minutesleft >= 0 ? 'Истекает через' : 'Истекло'}</span>
                        <span id="days"class="obschiyspan">${daysleft >= 0 ? daysleft : '0'}</span>
                        <span class="obschiyspan">дня(ей)</span>
                        <span id="hours" class="obschiyspan">${hoursLeft >= 0 ? hoursLeft : '0'}</span>
                        <span class="obschiyspan">часа(ов)</span>
                        <span id="minutes" class="obschiyspan">${minutesleft >= 0 ? minutesleft : '0'}</span>
                        <span class="obschiyspan">минут(ы)</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="Galochka">
                    `;
                    taskListOnDate.appendChild(taskItem);
                      // Устанавливаем интервал для обновления таймера
                        const interval = setInterval(() => {
                        const updateDifference = savedTaskTime - new Date();
                        const updateDaysLeft = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                        const updateHoursLeft = Math.floor((updateDifference % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                        const updateMinutesLeft = Math.floor((updateDifference % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                        document.getElementById('days').innerText = updateDaysLeft;
                        document.getElementById('hours').innerText = updateHoursLeft;
                        document.getElementById('minutes').innerText = updateMinutesLeft;
                             // Проверяем истекло ли время задачи
                        if (updateDifference < 0) {
                            clearInterval(interval);
                            archiveTask(savedTaskText, savedTaskTime.toISOString());
                            document.getElementById("timer").innerText = "Истекло";
                            taskItem.remove();
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                      // Обработчик события изменения состояния чекбокса
                    taskItem.querySelector('.Galochka').addEventListener('change', function() {
                        if (this.checked) {
                            archiveTask(savedTaskText, savedTaskTime.toISOString());
                            taskItem.remove();
                            clearInterval(interval);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
function archiveTask(taskText, taskTime) {
    let archivedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('archivedTasks')) || [];
    archivedTasks.push(`${taskText},${taskTime}`); 
    localStorage.setItem('archivedTasks', JSON.stringify(archivedTasks)); 

    for (let key in localStorage) {
        const taskData = localStorage.getItem(key);
        if (taskData && taskData.startsWith(taskText + ",")) {
            localStorage.removeItem(key);
            break; 
        }
    }
}

 

calendarDateInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
    displayTasksForDate(this.value);
});


displayTasksForDate(fixedDate);

document.querySelector('.burger_btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
    document.querySelector('.nav-button').classList.toggle('open');
})
document.querySelector('.tri-tochki').addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
    document.querySelector('.nav-help1').classList.toggle('open1');
})

и на всякий случай прикреплю script.js и arhiv.js

script.js
const taskInput = document.getElementById('taskInput');
const taskTimeInput = document.getElementById('taskTime'); 
const addTaskButton = document.getElementById('addTask'); 
const taskList = document.getElementById('taskList'); 

addTaskButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const taskText = taskInput.value;
    const taskTime = taskTimeInput.value;
    const currentUser = 'User1'; 

    if (taskText && taskTime) {
        const taskItem = document.createElement('li');
        const taskKey = currentUser + '_' + taskText;


        taskItem.innerHTML = `
            <span>${taskText}</span>         
            <span class="time">${new Date(taskTime).toLocaleString()}</span>         
            <button class='deleteTask'>Удалить</button>  
            <input type="checkbox" class="Galochka">`;

        localStorage.setItem(taskKey, `${taskText},${taskTime}`);
        taskList.appendChild(taskItem);
        taskInput.value = '';
        taskTimeInput.value = '';

        const deleteButton = taskItem.querySelector('.deleteTask');
        deleteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            taskList.removeChild(taskItem);
            localStorage.removeItem(taskText); 
        });

        const checkbox = taskItem.querySelector('.Galochka');
        checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
            if (checkbox.checked) {
                taskItem.innerHTML = `
                    <span>${taskText}</span>         
                    <span class="time">${new Date().toLocaleString()}</span>`;
                taskList.removeChild(taskItem);
                localStorage.removeItem(taskText); 
            }
        });
    }
});

document.querySelector('.burger_btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
    document.querySelector('.nav-button').classList.toggle('open');
})

document.querySelector('.tri-tochki').addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
    document.querySelector('.nav-help2').classList.toggle('open2');
})

arhiv.js
const archivedTaskList = document.getElementById('archivedTaskList');


function displayArchivedTasks() {
    archivedTaskList.innerHTML = "";
    let archivedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('archivedTasks')) || [];

    archivedTasks.forEach(taskData => {
        const taskDetails = taskData.split(",");
        const taskItem = document.createElement('li');
        taskItem.innerHTML = `<span>${taskDetails[0]}</span> <span>${new Date(taskDetails[1]).toLocaleString()}</span>`;
        archivedTaskList.appendChild(taskItem);
    });
}
const deleteArhiv = document.getElementById('deleteArhiv');
deleteArhiv.addEventListener('click', () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('archivedTasks'); 
    archivedTaskList.innerHTML = ""; 
    displayArchivedTasks();
});

document.querySelector('.burger_btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
    document.querySelector('.nav-button').classList.toggle('open');
})
document.querySelector('.tri-tochki').addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
    document.querySelector('.nav-help1').classList.toggle('open1');
})

displayArchivedTasks();


как задать хороший вопрос. начните с заголовка, где должно быть краткое описание сути вопроса, а не ваше жизнеописание.

тут смотрели ? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+localstorage
